# Problemas favicon.ico obtendo dos request!

Tags: php, codeigniter

He tratado de buscar la solución a este problema en varios foros, pero no veo nada concreto.

Uso el framwork `Codeigniter PHP` (Tengo la versión 2.1.0 de Codeigniter) y cada vez que mi aplicación carga una página, por ejemplo:

```
http://ejemplo.com/site/principal
```

En el access_log de Apache se observa.

```
/ejemplo.com/site/principal
/ejemplo.com/site/principal/favicon.ico
```

Cuando hay una petición a un controlador, siempre se duplica la llamada acabada el favicon.ico.
Al haber esta llamada adicional que procesa todo el framwork o hay error o da problemas.

He visto por ahí que hablan de especificar el favicon.ico con por ejemplo:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

O similares, la verdad he probado todas la opciones y tengo el favicon.ico en la raíz que lo carga correctamente, sin embargo las dos respuestas continuan.

Como forma preventiva en el fichero `routes.php` de `codeigniter` he puesto este código:

```
$pos_track = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "favicon.ico");

if ($pos_track !== false) {
    header ("Location: ".RUTA_WWW."/favicon.ico");
    exit;
}
```

De esta forma cualquier petición que tenga `favicon.ico` y pase por el framwork va al `favicon.ico` de la raíz.

Pero a ver si alguien sabe porque pasa esto y alguna forma más fina, si la hay, de solucionarlo.

Ejemplo:

http://miweb.com/site/id

adicionalmente en el log de apache también hay una llamada a `http://miweb.com/site/id/favicon.ico`, en cualquier controlador, a pesar de tener un fichero favicon.ico en la raíz y cargarse correctamente.

He probado a poner:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="short icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Incluso con un helper del codeigniter, pero nada llama dos veces.

---

Gracias todos por vuestras respuestas.

Me refiero al access_log de Apache. Cuando hay una petición a un controlador, siempre se duplica la llamada acabada el favicon.ico.

Ejemplo:

http://miweb.com/site/id

Pues esto se procesa correctamente, llama al controlador site y pasaria un paramentro. Pero adicionalmente en el log de apache también hay una llamada a

http://miweb.com/site/id/favicon.ico, en cualquier controlador, a pesar de tener un fichero favicon.ico en la raíz y cargarse correctamente.

Al haber esta llamada adicional que procesa todo el framwork o hay error o da problemas.

He probado a poner:

Incluso con un helper del codeigniter, pero nada llama dos veces.

Tengo la versión 2.1.0 de Codeigniter, que es un poco antigua, lo sé, no obstante no parece tener mucho sentido este problema.

Gracias de nuevo.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. A que te refieres con "en el logo de apache se observa?". Podrias explicarlo un poco mejor? No mucho entiendo que estas pregutnando.

Comment: Y cuáles son específicamente las 2 solicitudes que está haciendo?

Comment: probaste `rel="shortcut icon"`

Comment: Hola he puesto nueva información en la pregunta. Me refiria al access_log de apache, que a cada petición al controlador, genera dos llamadas, la correcta, y luego otra acaba en favicon.ico.